# What password encryption Jenkins is using?

Tags: java, jenkins, hudson

I am modifying an xml of a Jenkins job. There is a field which is a password. When I get the xml, where it was the raw password now there is a hash.

What I need is to know how to create this hash from the raw password value.

```
  <scm class="com.deluan.jenkins.plugins.rtc.JazzSCM">
    <username>user</username>
    <password>zlvnUMF1/hXwe3PLoitMpQ6BuQHBJ1FnpH7vmMmQ2qk=</password>
  </scm>
```

I have been reading Jenkins [source code](https://github.com/jenkinsci/jenkins/blob/0cc333faf285d587a87dee8a5ea54a4f75a2c758/core/src/main/java/hudson/security/HudsonPrivateSecurityRealm.java) and I think the class HudsonPrivateSecurityRealm.java is involved but I am not sure about the salt parameter.

PS: This is not for the Jenkins password is for a plugin which in the job configuration it has a password field.

Comment: If you know the cleartext password you could try out some common hashing algorithms.

Comment: In a comment of HudsonPrivateSecurityRealm class says that PasswordEncoder is based on SHA-256 and random salt generation. Hence the problem is how to get the salt used by Jenkins or how to generate the same salt, right?

Comment: Salts are generated when encrypting the password, and [included in the output](https://github.com/jenkinsci/jenkins/blob/0cc333faf285d587a87dee8a5ea54a4f75a2c758/core/src/main/java/hudson/security/HudsonPrivateSecurityRealm.java#L602-L603). Since that hash doesn't fit the format, it might well not be generated by this code — it's setup by a plugin, after all.

Answer (score 48):

In fact, it's not a hash but rather an encrypted password. I guess encryption keys are stored in the master node. Actually, you can decrypt the password by executing following groovy script on master's script console

```
import hudson.util.Secret

def secret = Secret.fromString("zlvnUMF1/hXwe3PLoitMpQ6BuQHBJ1FnpH7vmMmQ2qk=")
println(secret.getPlainText())
```

and if you want to encrypt the password, then

```
import hudson.util.Secret

def secret = Secret.fromString("your password")
println(secret.getEncryptedValue())
```

A password encrypted on a computer can be decrypted only on that particular computer since keys are randomly generated and obviously on different machines the keys are different.

Check out [core/src/main/java/hudson/util/Secret.java](https://github.com/jenkinsci/jenkins/blob/9c443c8d5bafd63fce574f6d0cf400cd8fe1f124/core/src/main/java/hudson/util/Secret.java) for more details

Comment: Any idea how to do this in Python? Or better yet, from the command line?

Answer (score 19):

Another possibility would be to execute a Groovy script via Jenkins Groovy console (you can reach it via **JENKINS_URL/script**):

```
println(hudson.util.Secret.decrypt("zlvnUMF1/hXwe3PLoitMpQ6BuQHBJ1FnpH7vmMmQ2qk="))
```

Some other ways would be possible with python:

https://github.com/tweksteen/jenkins-decrypt
https://gist.github.com/menski/8f9980999ed43246b9b2

Comment: Cool. To bad I don't have the correct rights there... xxxxis missing the Overall/RunScripts permission

Answer (score 17):

Jenkins uses [AES-128-ECB](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Advanced_Encryption_Standard) for all its encryptions. It basically uses the `master.key` file to encrypt the key stored in `hudson.util.Secret` file. This key is then used to encrypt the password in `credentials.xml`.

So to decrypt Jenkins password, you need basically access to `hudson.util.Secret` and `master.key` files. You can check exactly how Jenkins encrypts the password by looking into `hudson.utils.Secret` class and its `fromString` method. Basically the password is concatenated with a magic before being encrypted using KEY.

For more details, please check: [Credentials storage in Jenkins](http://xn--thibaud-dya.fr/jenkins_credentials.html).

---

To decrypt the password, follow these steps:

1. While logged in as admin in Jenkins, go to: `/script` page.
2. Run the following command:

   ```
   println(hudson.util.Secret.decrypt("{XXX=}"))
   ```

   or:

   ```
   println(hudson.util.Secret.fromString("{XXX=}").getPlainText())
   ```

   where `{XXX=}` is your encrypted password. This will print the plain password.

   To do opposite, run:

   ```
   println(hudson.util.Secret.fromString("some_text").getEncryptedValue())
   ```

<sup>Source: [gist at `tuxfight3r/jenkins-decrypt.groovy`](https://gist.github.com/tuxfight3r/eca9442ff76649b057ab).</sup>

---

Alternatively check the following scripts: [`tweksteen/jenkins-decrypt`](https://github.com/tweksteen/jenkins-decrypt),
 [`menski/jenkins-decrypt.py`](https://gist.github.com/menski/8f9980999ed43246b9b2).