# Extract passphrase from Jenkins' credentials.xml

Tags: jenkins

I have added an SSH credential to Jenkins.

Unfortunately, I have forgotten the SSH passphrase and would now like to obtain it from Jenkins' credential archive, which is located at `${JENKINS_HOME}/credentials.xml`.

That XML document seems to have credentials encrypted in XML tags `<passphrase>` or `<password>`.

How can I retrieve the plaintext passphrase?

Answer (score 199, accepted):

Open your Jenkins' installation's script console by visiting `http(s)://${JENKINS_ADDRESS}/script`.

There, execute the following Groovy script:

```
println( hudson.util.Secret.decrypt("${ENCRYPTED_PASSPHRASE_OR_PASSWORD}") )
```

where `${ENCRYPTED_PASSPHRASE_OR_PASSWORD}` is the encrypted content of the `<password>` or `<passphrase>` XML element that you are looking for.

Comment: And in order to get the password value of `${ENCRYPTED_PASSPHRASE_OR_PASSWORD}`: go to credentials, update, in the browser "See source code" and you will get the encrypted password in the data field for password. Then use that function.

Comment: What if I don't have access to `/script`. Means Jenkins overall access.

Comment: decrypt call worked for me without the dollar sign.

Answer (score 36):

First, you need to get the encrypted value which is conveniently placed in the `value` attribute of the password field of that credentials item you are interested in. Navigate to the credentials item in Jenkins UI you, click Inspect Element on the password field, and copy its `value` attribute (something like `{AQAABAAAa6VBbyzg5AWMW2RnfaBaj46}`

Then, go to `JENKINS_URL/script` and execute `println( hudson.util.Secret.decrypt("{AQAABAAAa6VBbyzg5AWMW2RnfaBaj46}") )`; decrypted password appears under the input field

Answer (score 24):

I know this is old, but... With pipelines it's extremely simple.  Here's an example pipeline that will print the credentials to the console:

```
node {
    def creds

    stage('Sandbox') {
        withCredentials([usernamePassword(credentialsId: 'my-creds', passwordVariable: 'C_PASS', usernameVariable: 'C_USER')]) {
            creds = "\nUser: ${C_USER}\nPassword: ${C_PASS}\n"
        }

        println creds
    }
}
```

Executing this pipeline produces the following in the console:

```
Started by user First Last (username)
Running in Durability level: MAX_SURVIVABILITY
[Pipeline] node
Running on Jenkins in /jenkins/workspace/sandbox
[Pipeline] {
[Pipeline] stage
[Pipeline] { (Sandbox)
[Pipeline] withCredentials
[Pipeline] {
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // withCredentials
[Pipeline] echo

User: testuser
Password: Ab37%ahc*z

[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // stage
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // node
[Pipeline] End of Pipeline
Finished: SUCCESS
```

The trick here is that the credentials are only masked inside the `withCredentials` block. If you assign them to a variable defined outside the block and then print that variable outside the block, no masking is applied.  This has been reported as a bug, however nothing is being done on it.

Comment: Wrap in `script { }` if using declarative pipeline syntax.

Comment: @Cartucho Which version of Jenkins did you check?

Comment: @Cartucho I just copy-pasted this code and ran in 2.176.2 - worked like a charm

Comment: @AleksG Interesting, I don't know why is failing in my environment.

Comment: does not work in declarative pipeline - prints ******

Comment: Works like charm for Jenkins version: 2.375.2

Answer (score 14):

Go to *Manage Jenkins -> Script Console* and run the following code:

```
import java.nio.charset.StandardCharsets;
def creds = com.cloudbees.plugins.credentials.CredentialsProvider.lookupCredentials(
      com.cloudbees.plugins.credentials.Credentials.class
)

for (c in creds) {
  println(c.id)
  if (c.properties.description) {
    println("   description: " + c.description)
  }
  if (c.properties.username) {
    println("   username: " + c.username)
  }
  if (c.properties.password) {
    println("   password: " + c.password)
  }
  if (c.properties.passphrase) {
    println("   passphrase: " + c.passphrase)
  }
  if (c.properties.secret) {
    println("   secret: " + c.secret)
  }
  if (c.properties.secretBytes) {
    println("    secretBytes: ")
    println("\n" + new String(c.secretBytes.getPlainData(), StandardCharsets.UTF_8))
    println("")
  }
  if (c.properties.privateKeySource) {
    println("   privateKey: " + c.getPrivateKey())
  }
  if (c.properties.apiToken) {
    println("   apiToken: " + c.apiToken)
  }
  if (c.properties.token) {
    println("   token: " + c.token)
  }
  println("")
}
```

Comment: I confirm that this is the easiest, and it works!

Answer (score 7):

If you are using the [Jenkins Credential Binding Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Credentials+Binding+Plugin?focusedCommentId=80184884), you can get it to write your password to a file.  You can't just output to the console, as the plugin will ***** it out.

[image: Credential Binding Plugin configuration to get password text on Windows]

Comment: Alternatively, you can somehow mangle the password, so that the plugin can't **** it out. E.g. as unix shell command: echo `$PASS | sed -e 's/./&-/g'?`.

Answer (score 3):

Yes you can get it back. It is AES encrypted and you have to do some things before like searching for the passphrase. Have a look into the [Secret](https://github.com/jenkinsci/jenkins/blob/master/core/src/main/java/hudson/util/Secret.java) class.

But you have look, there are already some scripts out there:

https://github.com/tweksteen/jenkins-decrypt
https://gist.github.com/menski/8f9980999ed43246b9b2

More information and a way to do it with java, can you find here:

[What password encryption Jenkins is using?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30953269/390177)