# Jenkins Decrypt API Token

Tags: encryption, jenkins, aes

I'm using Jenkins with DC/OS (Mesos) and the service doesn't have a standard login but instead uses Mesos/Zookeeper for authentication. I'm can access JENKINS_HOME and have the config files for each user. I see the config.xml and also see the secret.key. I found this code:

https://github.com/abrindeyev/jenkins-helpers/blob/master/bin/get_api_token.rb

whose purpose is to decode the Jenkins API Token from the config. However, when I run this I get the following error:

```
/root/decrypt_api.rb:28:in `final': wrong final block length (OpenSSL::Cipher::CipherError)
from /root/decrypt_api.rb:28:in `decrypt'
from /root/decrypt_api.rb:35:in `<main>'
```

Here's an example Token and Key (from a Docker Jenkins test container):

Cipher in config.xml:

```
<jenkins.security.ApiTokenProperty>
<apiToken>{AQAAABAAAAAwrkIhJkGOx+QkqgJ/Ep8NhecxeWcqAs78RI9v5kr8y1FSCJBA4YFHrneQGxmetsj3/xSywFRXItIbtuCufWR6ng==}</apiToken>
</jenkins.security.ApiTokenProperty>
```

Secret Key:

```
bdafc86eae946c35ca57d3af02a82b733741d59e1eca44e0a3f7ef0b8f25f8e6
```

How can I decode the Token with the cipher and the key?

Comment: Please tell me you've not actually just gone and posted your token and key here? You're going to want to change those after you get your answer.

Comment: As I've mentioned in the post this is from a Docker container that I've just spun up. I'm not using this instance for anything but testing.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Extract passphrase from Jenkins' credentials.xml](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37683143/extract-passphrase-from-jenkins-credentials-xml)

Answer (score 1):

You can decode Jenkins token by going to *Script Console* in your *master* node (or go to `/script`), then run the following command:

```
println(hudson.util.Secret.decrypt("{XXX=}"))
```

<sup>Note: Replace `{XXX=}` with your token string.</sup>

---

To decrypt it without using Jenkins, checkout these scripts:
 [`tweksteen/jenkins-decrypt`](https://github.com/tweksteen/jenkins-decrypt), [`menski/jenkins-decrypt.py`](https://gist.github.com/menski/8f9980999ed43246b9b2).

---

Related:

- [Extract passphrase from Jenkins' credentials.xml](https://stackoverflow.com/q/37683143/55075)
- [What password encryption Jenkins is using?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25547381/55075)
- [How to decrypt Jenkins passwords from credentials.xml?](https://devops.stackexchange.com/q/2191/3)

Answer (score 0):

go to
http://jenkins-host/script

```
hashed_pw='your-sercret-hash-S0SKVKUuFfUfrY3UhhUC3J'
passwd = hudson.util.Secret.decrypt(hashed_pw)
println(passwd)
```

it should decrypt your token